# Is there a way to package Tkinter into and android app?

Tags: android, tkinter

I like using tkinter as I am quite knowledgeable in it.

I was wondering if it was possible to package tkinter into an android app?

I know you can use kivy however I would prefer to use tkinter

Comment: Do you just like Python? What's Tkinter offer that the native Android framework does not?

Comment: I'm very new to coding and only know python, was just interested to see if you could make an APK out of a Tkinter program for Android.

Comment: Try QPython, then